# form-data request body is empty

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multipartform-data, multer

I'm trying to send an image and some data from an API to another. The image is stored in memory with multer. But when I want to send it, the body is just empty. I tried the same request with postman and it worked perfectly.

*postman test*
[postman test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJZYw.png)

*server test*
[server test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmt15.png)

*Here is some code. I removed some of it so you can read it better*

```
export const saveImage = async ({ image, name, folder, options }: { image: any, name?: any, folder: string, options?: any }) => {
    try {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", image.buffer, image.originalname);
        if(options) {
            fd.append("options[resize][height]", options?.resize?.height);
            fd.append("options[resize][width]", options?.resize?.width);
        }
        if(name) fd.append("name", name);
        fd.append("folder", folder);
        fd.append("servideId", IMAGES_ID);
        fd.append("serviceSecret", IMAGES_SECRET);

        console.log(fd)

        const formHeaders = fd.getHeaders();

        const request = await axios.post(`${IMAGES_URL}/api/images`, {
            headers: formHeaders,
            body: fd
        });

        return request.data.id;
    } catch (error) {
        const { response } = error;
        console.log(response.request.data)
        if(error?.response?.data?.error) {
            throw { statusCode: error.response.status, message: error.response.data.error }
        }
        console.error("Images API", error);
        throw new InternalError("Something gone wrong");
    }
}
```

When I log the FormData, I can see in _streams, the data that I'm sending, but the Images API receives an empty body.
[FormData screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK0PA.png)

If you need more information tell me, please! Thank you

Comment: You have a typo: "servideId". Could you paste the backend multer code that prints the empty object?

Comment: @Maxim Thanks! I've corrected it. That typo was causing some problems too haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [axios API](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) for the post method is: `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`. The second argument *must always* be the data you send along.

In your case axios thinks `{ headers: formHeaders, body: fd }` is the body and the request ends up being application/json. To send a file with data using axios in Node.js, do the following:

```js
const response = await axios.post(`${IMAGES_URL}/api/images`, fd, {
  headers: {
    ...formHeaders,
    'X-Custom-Header': 'lala', // optional
  },
});
```

Your question inspired me to turn this answer into an article — [Send a File With Axios in Node.js](https://maximorlov.com/send-a-file-with-axios-in-nodejs/). It covers a few common pitfalls and you'll learn how to send files that are stored as a Buffer or coming from a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

With Axios, you can directly use the form data without having to deal with headers.

`axios.post("/api/images", fd)`

If you wish to modify headers at some point in the future, you should pass the formData to the `data` field instead of `body`.

`axios.post("/api/images", { headers: formHeaders, data: fd })`

Correction in comments.

It can also be done using the [Axios API syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api).

`axios({method: 'post', url: 'url', data: fd, headers: {} })`

In the backend, multer will add your files to `req.file` instead of `req.body`, if you have properly configured it to do so.

Comment: The axios API for post is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`, therefore the second argument must always be data. In your second example the config object is seen as data by axios library and the request ends up being application/json. This works instead: `axios.post('/api/images', fd, { headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'lala' } })`.

Comment: @MaximOrlov, you are correct. I accidentally mixed the `axios.post` API with the [Axios API syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api). Thanks for pointing it out!